# Как натягивать данные изображения на wordpress с acf?

Tags: wordpress, acf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условие такое, что этих картинок будет фиксированное кол-во, которое вы видите на скрине.
Как правильно их натянуть? Нормально ли будет, если просто взять и создать 6 полей acf под каждую картинку? Или же есть другой способ, более удобный?

Comment: Поле [Gallery](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) или [Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) внутри которого будет поле `Image`. Но `Gallery` удобнее в данном случае, как по мне.

Comment: @Simon А если у меня не прошка, а обычный acf? :)

Comment: Тогда попробуйте [этот плагин](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/)